# How to implement a conditional with message in the API with Nodejs and javaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to NodeJs with JavaScript, I took a ready example and I just want to add a condition in the body of the API of type: If that value exists, it shows the message in the API call by Insonmia or Postman and does not allow it to be included.

my code in VSCODE

```
const express = require('express')
const server = express()

server.use(express.json())


const users = ["Nunu", "Nininha", "Lóló", "Scooby"]

server.get('/users', (req, res) => {

return res.json(users)
})

server.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.body
    users.push(name)
       if (name == "Drol") {
        console.log("Existing dog") // ***I want this message to appear in the body of the API when it is called via Postman or Insonmia***
      }

      return res.json(users)
  
})

My code by API Insonmia
**POST**    http://localhost:3000/users
{
"name": "Drol
```

Comment: Replace the `console.log` statement with `return res.json({ message: "Existing dog"})`

Comment: Thank you Yousaf!!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have consistency in your responses you'll need to still using res.json

```
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.body;
    if (users.includes(name)) {
        return res.json({
            message: 'Existing dog'
        })
    } else {
        users.push(name)
    }
    res.json(users)
})
```

If you want to send plain text you can use `res.send("Existing dog")`

Comment: Sensacional Jose Alberto... Muito agradecido de coração!!.. Deu super-certo!!..